# What is a Viterbi algorithm that exploits sparseness of transition matrix?

Tags: dynamic-programming

What is a Viterbi algorithm that exploits sparseness of transition matrix?

In

PYIN: A FUNDAMENTAL FREQUENCY ESTIMATOR
USING PROBABILISTIC THRESHOLD DISTRIBUTIONS
Matthias Mauch and Simon Dixon
[https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~simond/pub/2014/MauchDixon-PYIN-ICASSP2014.pdf](https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Esimond/pub/2014/MauchDixon-PYIN-ICASSP2014.pdf)

the authors write:

> the HMM is decoded
> using an **efficient version of the Viterbi algorithm** that exploits
> the sparseness of the transition matrix.

I have not been able to find how such version differs from a typical Viterbi algorithm. I also speculated that it does not differ in implementation, but merely performs better by excluding all zero elements.